# Godot: Change node position in keyframe

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm doing a game in Godot, and I created a simple move animation with AnimationPlayer that moves the node from position A to position B. The animation is two keyframes.

Now I want to change position B with code, how can I do it?

I was thinking something like this:

```
func moveTo(pos):
    get_node("animation").get_animation("move").get_keyframe(1).set_pos(pos)
    get_node("animation").play("move")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need use the `_process(delta)` to do this.
Animations are constant and can not be changed during execution.

You can use the `look_to(position)` and `translate(0,0, delta)` functions while you are away from position.

If it is a location with obstacles, you can use a navmesh to move the node.